# Is there any Watson or Bluemix API to be able to work with OCR (Optical Character Recognition)?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Is there any Watson or Bluemix API to be able to work with OCR?

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual Recognition](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition.html) service used to have a text recognition feature. It was available in the earlier beta version of the service, but has since been moved to closed beta according to the [release notes](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/releasenotes.shtml):

> Text recognition is now closed beta - We have gone back into a closed beta with the `POST` and `GET` `/v3/recognize_text` methods. We look forward to continuing to support BETA clients using the service, with no current plans for another open beta.

Comment: The API appears to still work though - I created a Watson Visual Recognition service a few days ago in Bluemix and i'm able to make /v3/recognise_text calls despite not being part of a closed beta (as far as I know). I've only tried a limited range of fairly clean test images but it appears to work reasonably well.

Comment: Ah, interesting! That's good to know, @strmqm. Thanks for the update!